# Eclipse: Iteration's count while Debugging a for each loop

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Can we know the count of the iteration (that is whether it's the first, second, third ... iteration ) while we are stepping over the code in a for each loop, in the eclipse debugger? Eclipse must be holding a count but how to get it show it to us. Apart from the workarounds of introducing an index in the code can we utilize something in built in eclipse.

Comment: Why do you think eclipse holds a counter?

Comment: To iterate over all the values in a list, it must be keeping track of the list and its size....

Comment: @JohnDoe why would it need a counter to do that? It can simply check if there is a next element and then get that next element just like iterators work. No counter required for iteration at all.

Comment: Hmmm, so we can not get the number of the iteration we are currently in, in case of a for loop.

Comment: Quite frankly: I don't know. Maybe eclipse does have an inbuilt counter for debugging iterations and maybe not. I was simply adressing the point that the idea that it must have one or otherwise iteration wouldn't work isn't really correct.

Comment: I meant to say that we can not get to know the number of the iteration in case of the for each loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can initiate a counter and increment it in the for loop, it should be a workaround.

You can track the variable under Eclipse console below:
[image]

Comment: Apart from the workaround, is there in built thing which we can exploit.

Comment: @JohnDoe Sorry, I have no idea about it.